# Does baking soda permanently eliminate nutritional properties of vitamin C?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

(Please forgive me for asking this if it's obvious, but it's not obvious to me.)

**EDIT: I am easily confused by chemistry, so please give me a very simple answer, followed by any lengthy further explanation (if you feel it's needed.) Please pretend you are speaking to a 5 year old. Thank you in advance.**

Does baking soda (sodium bicarbonate?) permanently eliminate vitamin C's nutritional properties? [This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73595/why-dont-effervescent-vitamin-c-tablets-react-with-the-vitamin-c) seems to say baking soda would not. Am I correct?

Comment: "Denature" isn't the right word, vit. C gets *oxidised*, by many things, but NaHCO3 isn't one of them.

Comment: I don't know what that means in terms of this question, but I'll reword it. Thank you.

Comment: Sodium bicarbonate causes mildly alkaline pH, at which L-ascorbic acid ( vitamin C ) oxidizes in solutions by aerial oxygen  faster than alone. Just for illustration, concentrated acid solutions strongly alkalized by sodium hydroxide turns from colourless to thick yellow rather quickly.

Comment: So, the charlatans pushing lemon juice and bicarbonate are actually pushing beverages with reduced vit C content....

Comment: @Alchimista So, is that a question for Poutnik or a statement/answer for me?

Comment: It something funny that the above material makes me realise